# Install WPF application using only .Net Framework

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have developed WPF application using VS 2013.

How do I install this application and run in some other PC without Visual Studio, using just only framework?

Comment: Do you mean you need to know how to publish it so you can run the executable?

Comment: Are your users on all on corporate network (if so ClickOnce could be a good option)?

Answer (score 3):

A good way to distribute WPF applications, is [ClickOnce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClickOnce)

You can place your application on a server, users can click on the link to install it.  If you like, you can provide settings to automatically check for updates.

The application can be made to run in an offline mode, and will make an entry under the Start button as well as in Control Panel to allow uninstall.

It will run in an Isolated Storage sandbox, so this may not be appropriate for all applications, or may require some minor code changes.  But, I have had many programs that just worked when turned into ClickOnce deployments.

NOTE:  You may want to invest in a code signing cert to remove any warnings the end user will see.  Or adjust Code Access Security of the destination machines if they are within your control.

Answer (score 1):

The right answer ready depends on a few factors;

1. Where are your users (anywhere, corp. network)
2. How often do you want to update the application, should it be automatic
3. Will you deploy a database

As it stands this link provides some options
[Deploying a WPF Application (WPF)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969776%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

If you update the questions with more detail, perhaps we can provide more specific suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way - ClickOnce. To use it: Project -> Property -> Publish. Another popular option - InnoSetup (http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php).